# Java AbstractQueuedSynchronizer and the template method pattern

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, reentrantlock, template-method-pattern

While reading the source code of `ReentrantLock`, I found that internally it use a synchronizer which extends `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` to control the lock. Doug Lea mentioned in this [paper](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/papers/aqs.pdf) that `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` serves as a "template method pattern", which helps simplify the coding of sub-classes.

However, Joshua Bloch advised in *Effective Java* that we should "favor composition over inheritance", because "unlike method invocation, inheritance violates encapsulation". And in my understanding, the "templates" in Spring (e.g. `RedisTemplate`, `TransactionTemplate`, etc.) [follow this rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33153252/why-is-jdbctemplate-an-example-of-the-template-method-design-pattern).

So, back to the `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` and the synchronizer defined in `ReentrantLock`, I would like to know if its design (based on template method pattern) has any disadvantages. Many thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you already know the disadvantages of inheritance. What more are you looking for?

Comment: @jaco0646 Yes I know the principle of "composition over inheritance", but it would be appreciated if someone can help explain it by the example of synchronizer in `ReentrantLock` :-)

Answer (score 1):

In case of `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` there are no disadvantages, because `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` is carefully [written](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11/blob/jdk-11+28/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java) in such a way that inheritance doesn't violate encapsulation:

- there are no visible fields for child classes
- all methods (except 5 protected ones) are `final`, so child classes cannot change them
- child classes are allowed to override only 5 protected methods: `tryAcquire()`, `tryRelease()`, `tryAcquireShared()`, `tryReleaseShared()` and `isHeldExclusively()`

Effectively this implementation is equivalent to composition: just move the 5 overridable methods to a dedicated interface.